# Webpack build fails with es6 react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I use React.js, Webpack, ...props syntax, arrow functions.

When I run "npm run build", I get this error:

**ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:» [bundle.js:77854,15]**

Here is my `debug.log`

[image]

My `webpack.config`

[image]

How to run build successfully?

---

I found the line which causes the bug, here it is:

`import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';`

I don't know why. :(

Without it, all my ES6 syntax works and compiled without any errors.

Any Help please

Comment: If you're trying to compress the bundle output file with UglifyJS2 it might be that it doesn't support ES6...

Comment: You could compress it manually with https://jscompress.com/ though (it looks like this compressor is using an ES6 compressor individually; check the ECMAScript 2016 (experimental) option)

Comment: Also, are you minifying the bundle with babel ? I never used it :v, but it probably supports ES6 and there are some related questions

Comment: I'm a newbie of Webpack. I don't really understand this. I followed a tutorial, did some react and now I try to build but doesnt work. BUT the --watch command to compile DEV bundle work great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

React-Bootstrap-Table have a dependency named React-Modal.

I installed React Modal by `npm install react-modal` without `--save` or `--save-dev`. So React-Modal wasn't not listed in  my `package.json`.

Now everything is ok.

**SOLUTION** :  `npm install react-modal --save`

Answer (score 1):

This error happens if you use have an npm dependency that has ES6 syntax. It happended to me, too, with Preact (see https://github.com/developit/preact-compat/issues/155).

You can fix it by adding the dependency explicitly to the modules that are loaded through babel, like so:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: [
                srcPath,
                // we need to include preact-compat
                // otherwise uglify will fail
                // @see https://github.com/developit/preact-compat/issues/155
                path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../node_modules/preact-compat/src')
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Oh! Yeah, okay! It looks good but In my case what is the dependency which needs to be add in the include ?

Comment: @Steffi babel-loader

Comment: no, babel-loader is not included in the bundle. Look in the package.json files of your dependencies, if they have a property "jsnext:main", you need to explicitly run them through babel for Uglify to work

Comment: @handoncloud I'm not blind, the babel-loader is in the webpack config, but it is not included in the bundle. I'm talking about configuring the babel-loader explicitly to include a package from node_modules that has the jsnext:main property. Currently, Steffi is only running her own source code through the babel-loader

Comment: Find out which module you have to include to be loaded through babel-loader. Check each dependency's package.json, see if it has a property jsnext:main

Answer (score 0):

In `bundle.js`, line 77854, character 15, there is a parenthese after a object properties name, instead of a :. 
There must be something like :

```
{property () {}}
```

instead of

```
{property : function () {}}
```

Edit (thanks to @handoncloud): The first is valid ES6, and is a shorthand for the second, that is the equivalent in ES5.

The problem is, that the build does not fully support ES6.

Comment: Found it. I think it from the plugin React-Modal : http://i.imgur.com/uXYeBNr.png (bundle.js) — http://i.imgur.com/kvXZLw6.png (react-modal.js) But how to solve that ? It's not my code. I just compile it with webpack...

Comment: `{property() {} }` is something valid in ES6, just fyi (inside an object expression, not block statement). It's a shorthand method

Comment: @Steffi Are you talking about `removePotal` ? Maybe Babel is trying to compress that input as ES5 or below. This is totally valid in ES5 yes.

Comment: If ES6 isn't supported, then just define it with the regular function syntax.

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand better so what is the solution?

Comment: @Steffi You should configure the babel-loader in order to support ES6, otherwise you'll need to manually fit ES6 syntax to ES5 (for example) syntax. That's easy, but there'll be many other things to change, probably.

Comment: Ok @handoncloud, so i prefer to configure babel-loader to es6, but how to configure that?

Comment: @Steffi Check https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options. I never used babel and babel-loader, but it also depends if you want it. Do you need babel to do something (i.e., make a ES6 code compatible to ES5 and etc.)?

Comment: @Steffi as I said in the comments, I think the problem (syntax error) is possibly related to babel-loader, it might be automatically running UglifyJS, treating the bundle as non ES6+ code.

Comment: @Steffi Oh ! Are you following this tutorial (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html)? Then your file extension must be .jsx. But you can also change your webpack configuration to find .js files. **Edit**: I've seen your entry file has a .jsx extension.

Comment: @handoncloud I followed a similar tutorial, not this one. but my files are already .jsx. But not my plugins I installed by npm

Comment: While I'm not sure on how to use babel and babel-loader, the only thing I can suggest is to transpile the ES6 codes... http://babeljs.io/repl/ but, well, you may need ES6 polyfills depending on the code